# PowerShell Script Logging

Tags: c#, powershell, logging, powershell-2.0

I call a PowerShell Script trough c#.net.
After calling the script nothing happens, and I don’t get any error to track the issues.
I need the output of the complete script execution.

Is it possible to write the PowerShell log/output somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `Start-Transcript` method will not work because we are not in the PS console session, this leaves us with a few alternatives in Powershell v 2.0.

One method I like is Write-Host combined with Add-Content, so I can both see and retain certain results.  If you are in the pipeline you can use the Out-File -Append

`Write-Host $Data;Add-Content $Output $Data;`

`Out-File -Append -FilePath $Output`

Tee-Object cannot append from Powershell v2, so I would avoid it unless you cannot.